# Construct cut off function in the product form $\rho_1\otimes \rho_2\otimes...\otimes \rho_m$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A_i\subset \Bbb{R}^n$,for $1\le i\le m$ are closed subset $\Bbb{R}^n$.Let $A_i^\epsilon$ denote the set $A_i+\overline{B_\epsilon(0)}$ which is also closed.Let $K$ be some **closed** subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$,Further suppose $A_1^\epsilon\times....\times A_m^\epsilon\bigcap K$ and $A_1\times....\times A_m\bigcap K$ are compact.

Prove there exist some cut-off function in the form $\rho_1(x_1)\otimes \rho_2(x_2)\otimes...\otimes \rho_m(x_m) = \rho(x_1,...,x_m)$ where $x_i\in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\rho_i \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ satisfy the condition:

$\rho$ is supported on $A_1^\epsilon\times....\times A_m^\epsilon\bigcap K$ this compact set and constant 1 on neiborhood of $A_1\times....\times A_m\bigcap K$

Moreover can we choose each $\rho_i$ that are constant 1 on neiborhood of $A_i$ for each $i$

It seems no matter which $K$ is choosen the cut off function is not possible?

I found this question in F. G. Friedlander, M. Joshi  Introduction to the Theory of Distributions page 56 as below:

[image]

Comment: If you can solve this for $m=1$ you can solve this for every $m$.

Comment: @daw Hi can you elaborate more,for $m = 1$ the intersection $K$ seems to be the obstacle,since we can only construct cut off that supported on  $A^\epsilon$ and constant 1 on neiborhood of $A$ how to deal with the $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be impossible without restrictions on $K$ (or a clarification what $\otimes$ is doing). Let
$$
K:= \{ (x_1,x_2) : \ |x_1+x_2| \le 1, \ |x_1| \le 1\}.
$$
Let now $\phi_1,\phi_2$ be smooth cut-off functions with values in $[0,1]$. In order that
$\phi(x_1,x_2) =\phi_1(x_1)\phi_2(x_2)=1$ for $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ it is necessary that
$$
\phi_1(0)=\phi_1(1)=\phi_2(0)=\phi_2(1)=1,
$$
which implies $\phi(1,1)=1$. But $(1,1)\not\in K$. Hence every cut-off function of the product form that is equal to one on $K$ has support much larger than $K$.

Comment: thanks @daw I  found this is a typo in the book,so the question is invalid I found someone has same question as me see here :http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/friedlander-errata.pdf page 4