# construct cut-off function in the tensor product form $\rho_1\otimes \rho_2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $K$ be compact subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$,prove given $K^\epsilon = K+\overline{B}_\epsilon$,there exist some cutoff function that support in $K^\epsilon$ and constant one on neiborhood of $K$.

I do as follows:Let $\pi_i$ be the projection on the corresponding coordinate,then we can see exist $\rho_1$ support on $\pi_1(K^\epsilon)$ and constant 1 on neiborhood of $\pi_1(K)$ (e.g denote it $N_1$).Similar for the second coordinate,hence $\rho_1(x_1)\otimes \rho_2(x_2)$ then we know it's constant 1 on neiboorhood of $K$ , the question is how to guarantee it support on $K^\epsilon$.

Comment: I think my counterexample to your previous question applies here as well. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3949852/construct-cut-off-function-in-the-product-form-rho-1-otimes-rho-2-otimes-o

Comment: @daw Yes....You are right thanks :)